# How can I find the CiviCRM Admin API key from Wordpress CiviCRM plugin

Tags: api

We have got a wordpress website using CiviCRM plugin. The only thing which we have is the CiviCRM site key, but in order to implement the functionality on the website we need CiviCRM API Key.

Can you or anyone please advise from where can we get those details?

Urgent help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: As an addition to @ramesh answer, here's a very good explanation on how to do it with the API Explorer: http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/9946/872

Comment: @Andrei I would vote for this to be the answer!  Unfortunately, since it's a comment, it can't be marked as the answer.  Pulling in Ramesh's link would probably make it even more complete.

Answer (score 3):

you can find API key against each contact record in the Database

select api_key from civicrm_contact where id = <>

Also please read the below link for more reference 
https://civicrm.org/extensions/api-key

I guess this helps !!!